Extend life of temporary using rval ref to ternary operator fails for non copyable types
consider:
struct S
{
    S() = default;  // ✓
    S(S const&) = delete;  // copy ✗
};

void f(S* a)
{
    S&& s = a ? *a : S{};
}

int main()
{
    f(0);
}

https://godbolt.org/z/s7v9v7Mdo
problem:

error: use of deleted function 'S::S(const S&)'

intent:
Use rvref to extend temporary life of E2 in ternary E0 ? E1 : E2. Work with s in f as an alias to either a ref to an outer scoped instance, or an inner scoped instance.
question:
Why S copy constructor appears to be invoked —or required to be accessible— at all?
notes:
S&& s = E0 ? S{} : S{} builds in gcc, but not msvc.
casting both sides builds under clang & gcc, not msvc: S&& s = E0 ? (S&&)*a : (S&&)S{};
